# How to reset Magento transactional emails ID?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have tried already to truncate core_email_template, with no success.
Even though I have deleted my previous transactional emails, as soon as I create a new one, the ID increments from my previous template.
I want it to start over from ID=1.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, some MySQL versions don't properly reset auto-increment values when using

```
TRUNCATE table_name;
```

Alternatively you can try to reset it directly:

```
ALTER TABLE `core_email_template` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```